# YII CGridView: Binding a jquery function after page change

Tags: php, jquery, yii, cgridview

I am using CGridView widget, with page size 5

I m trying to bind a jquery function which i want to run after the page change has occurred by clicking on next, back or page number buttons.

i have tried to do it by hooking into the click functions on these buttons...

```
$("ul#yw1 li a").live('click', function(e) {
    turnOnButtons();
})
```

But the issue is, this turnOnButtons() runs before page change. i want it to run after the page has been changed.

Is there a way to run my function after the next/previous page on CGridVoew has rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply set [`afterAjaxUpdate`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail) `CGridView` property, e.g. :

```
$this->widget('application.widgets.CGridView',array(
    // ...
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id, data){ turnOnButtons(); }',
    // ...
));
```